Tableview on scrolling values changing from adapter
I develop both android(Java) and IOS(swift) applications. I had a problem on the Android side and I solved it.I'm having the same problem on the IOS side but I couldn't solve it.
I have a tableview in my application and I fill it with data I get from my own server.
However, when I swipe through the list, sometimes the values ​​and images in the list item get mixed up between the list items.
This little code on the Android side solved my problem
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

I searched for override methods but I couldn't find an equivalent event that would solve my problem.

The list interface is like this, a simple list.

Maybe there is a problem with uploading the images, I upload it like this
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableCell
        let item = radio_type_list[indexPath.row]
        cell.RadioTitle.text = item.title
        cell.RadioDescription.text = item.desc
        cell.RadioImage.downloadImageFrom(link:item.imageurl, contentMode: UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill)
        return cell;
    }

let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImageFrom(link:String, contentMode: UIView.ContentMode) {
        let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, AnyObject>()
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: (link as AnyObject) as! NSString) {
                    self.image = cachedImage as? UIImage
                    self.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
                    return
                }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask( with: NSURL(string:link)! as URL, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.contentMode =  contentMode
                if let data = data { self.image = UIImage(data: data) }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}


You can learn more about dequeue mechanisim of ios following this link
So when you scroll through your list, whenever a cell get dequeue, you start a download image task from an UIImageView. The problem arise when cell got reuse, there is a chance the old download task take longer time than the new download task one for that cell. Here is my suggestion code to fix your problem:
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "mainCell", for: indexPath) as! MainTableCell
    let item = radio_type_list[indexPath.row]
    cell.RadioTitle.text = item.title
    cell.RadioDescription.text = item.desc
    cell.bind(imageUrl: item.imageurl, contentMode: UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill)
    return cell;
}

class MainTableCell: UITableViewCell {
    var RadioImage = UIImageView()
    
    var imageUrl: String = ""
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        RadioImage.image = nil // remove old image
    }
    
    func bind(imageUrl: String, contentMode: UIView.ContentMode) {
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        RadioImage.downloadImageFrom(link: imageUrl, contentMode: contentMode) { [weak self] _image, contentMode, imageUrl in
            guard let self = self,
                  self.imageUrl == imageUrl // <- compare to current imageUrl of cell to display image correctly
            else { return }
            self.RadioImage.image = _image
            self.RadioImage.contentMode = contentMode
        }
    }
}

let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>()
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImageFrom(link:String, contentMode: UIView.ContentMode, completion: ((UIImage, UIView.ContentMode, String) -> Void)?) {
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: (link as AnyObject) as! NSString) {
            completion?(cachedImage, .scaleAspectFill, link)
                    return
                }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask( with: NSURL(string:link)! as URL, completionHandler: {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let data = data,
                   let image = UIImage(data: data)
                {
                    imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: link as NSString)
                    completion?(image, contentMode, link)
                }
            }
        }).resume()
    }
}


While this is likely the correct overall approach, it makes little sense for the downloadImageFrom function to be in an extension to UIImageView since the image view is never used inside the downloadImageFrom function.

@HangarRash totatlly agree with you, a refactor approach could be creating a class inherits from UIImageView to encapsulate fetch logic or we can just use a library like SDWebImage :)

This was the solution for me thank you very much @duckSern1108
I try not to use additional libraries in applications as much as I can.

Cheers, Happy coding :D

@duckSern1108 All I meant is that downloadImageFrom has nothing to do with UIImageView. Put that method in the custom cell class or some utility caching class. No need for a 3rd party library and definitely no need to subclass UIImageView.

The issue you’re experiencing occurs because the images get mixed up or swapped between cells as they scroll in and out of view
let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, UIImage>() 

extension UIImageView {
    func downloadImageFrom(link: String, contentMode: UIView.ContentMode) {
        self.contentMode = contentMode
        self.image = nil // Clear the image initially to prevent reuse issues

       
        if let cachedImage = imageCache.object(forKey: link as NSString) {
            self.image = cachedImage
            return
        }
        
 
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: link)!) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, let downloadedImage = UIImage(data: data) else {
                return
            }

            // Cache the downloaded image
            imageCache.setObject(downloadedImage, forKey: link as NSString)
            
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.image = downloadedImage
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}

